# ESP32 AsyncWebServer SPIFFS problem loading page

Tags: esp32, spiffs

I can load spiff docs, but I get a 404.  Wireless works, IP addressing works and I can load other examples successfully.  This simple image load ino is giving me fits!

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
const char *ssid = "x";
const char *password =  "123456789";
IPAddress staticIP(10,0,0,1); //ESP static ip
IPAddress gateway(0,0,0,0);   //IP Address of your WiFi Router (Gateway)
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);  //Subnet mask

AsyncWebServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
{request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.htm", "text/html");});
     
server.on("/image.png", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
{request->send(SPIFFS, "/image.png", "image/png");});

server.begin();

}//END setup

void loop() 
{
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset='UTF-8'>
</head>
<body>
     <img src="image.png" alt=" image goes here">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an ESP32 to test with.  Though, I tried to make your code run on an ESP8266, but it's a bit of an effort to validate what is ultimately a wild guess on my part.

And that is: *perhaps* you have some uppercase letters in your filename such that `"/image.png"` does not match perfectly and furthermore *maybe* SPIFFS is case sensitive.  That is, your file could be named Image.png or IMAGE.png and that might matter.

UPDATE:

In my exploring this on the ESP8266, I'd forgotten to execute `SPIFFS.begin()`.  And I see no counterpart to it in your code.
At least one example of ESPAsyncWebServer I've seen [does call `SPIFFS.begin()`](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/blob/3c6f5f9/examples/ESP_AsyncFSBrowser/ESP_AsyncFSBrowser.ino#L133)

I found that the filenames **are** case sensitive, again at least on the ESP8266; so that can be a source of problems.

Also checked that if the SPIFFS size is changed through menu selections, I did indeed need to reupload the SPIFFS image.

I know these are different systems; in fact the code I'm using to test doesn't compile for ESP32, but I suspect a lot of the code is shared, and so maybe the problems are as well.

Comment: This is it!  Thanks for taking the time.